# Value of most accurate measurement of vacuum energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, vacuum

I have seen it many places on the Internet that they give an approximate estimate as to how much energy there is in vacuum. But I want to do some calculations and for that I need the most accurate measurement of vacuum energy.
So can someone give me the accurate numbers.

Comment: [Planck 2018 results](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06209)

Comment: Cosmological observations indicate that if it exists at all,the vacuum energy is at least 40 orders of magnitude less than the figure required by quantum mechanics,so you are very unlikely to get a figure as accurate as the one you are asking for.

Comment: @MichaelWalsby cosmological observations indicate that it definitely exists.